# Enabling Surface Constraints on a LASD in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, modelbuilder, lidar, lasd

I'm working on a LAS processing model. I have been able to:

- create a LASD from a folder of LAS files.
- create a mask from the LASD.
- apply the mask (called Surface Constraints) to the LASD file.

However, because I cannot toggle it as "selected" via a ModelBuilder tool, then none of the subsequent analysis honors the mask. I have checked that running my next process (LASD to Raster) does behave as expected if I select it.

Am I missing a tool or is it missing from the tool set for 10.3? If it's available in any of the upgrades I'd be interested to know (10.4, 10.5, Pro 1.4) as well.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First, check that there's a default (valid) value for Surface Constraints in your model.  If you don't have a default value the model recognizes as valid, you can get screwy results or a model that just won't run.

Next, check that the Surface constraints mask is a prerequisite to the rest of your operations.  Sounds like you have an iterator in there, so what about recalculating the mask every time through the loop?  It ain't elegant, but it might well get the job done and you can then spend time looking for a less kludge-y solution.

If that doesn't work, try putting all the iteration stuff into a submodel with that mask as a parameter of said submodel.